# Is this the correct way to use a CreateView in Django with an inlineformset_factory?

Tags: django

I've got one master detail relationship beteen Article and Section, and wish to allow a user to add sections on the same page before creating the Article.

It seems to work, but I'm also very new to Django, and wonder if I'm doing it right. There's a lot going on here, and I wonder if I'm overriding methods correctly, for example, and when I do, is the content correct?

A gold-standard way of doing it would be very appreciated!

```
class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    template_name = 'articles/article_add.html'
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    SectionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Article, Section, extra=2, can_delete=False, fields=('content',))

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('get called on article create view')
        self.object = None   #what does this achieve?
        
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=self.get_form(),
                                  section_form=self.SectionFormSet(),
                                  ))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('post called on article create view')
        self.object = None
     
        form = self.get_form()
        section_form = self.SectionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        
        if (form.is_valid() and section_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, section_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, section_form)

    
    def form_valid(self, form, section_form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        if section_form.is_valid():
            print('section form is valid')
            self.object = form.save()
            section_form.instance = self.object
            section_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)    
        #return super().form_valid(form)
        
        '''
            return self.render_to_response( self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  section_form=section_form,
                                  ))
        '''
    

    def form_invalid(self, form, article_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  article_form=article_form))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is 100% correct, but it seems better than my previous code :

```
class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    template_name = 'articles/article_add.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    SectionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Article, Section, extra=2, can_delete=False, fields=('content',))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['section_form'] = self.SectionFormSet(self.request.POST,instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['section_form'] = self.SectionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def save_sections(self):
        try:
            context = self.get_context_data()
            section_form = context['section_form']
            if section_form.is_valid():
                #section_form.instance = self.object
                section_form.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to save section: ' + str(e))


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form) #save article form 
        self.save_sections()
        return response

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('index')
```

here's the update view (for completion), pretty much identical except it gets the instance of the article in the formset factory

```
class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'articles/ArticleUpdate.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    model = Article
    SectionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Article, Section, extra=0, can_delete=False, fields=('content',))

    def test_func(self):
        article = self.get_object()
        
        if self.request.user == article.author or self.request.user.is_superuser :
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('get context data called update view')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['section_form'] = self.SectionFormSet(self.request.POST,instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['section_form'] = self.SectionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def save_sections(self):
        print('save sections called update view')
        try:
            context = self.get_context_data()
            section_form = context['section_form']
            if section_form.is_valid():
               # section_form.instance = self.object  #if im passing instance in the factory, do I need it here to?
                section_form.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to save section: ' + str(e))


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form valid called update view')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form) #save article form 
        self.save_sections()
        return response

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('index')
```